# How can I solve enum associated type with deferent value type in Swift when accessing the value of them?

Tags: swift

Here is my test enum:

```
enum TestEnum {

    case name(String)
    case age(Int)
    case employed(Bool)

    var value: Any {
        switch self {
        case .name(let string):
            return string
        case .age(let int):
            return int
        case .employed(let bool):
            return bool
        }
        
    }
}
```

As you can see in codes I have multi cases with deferent associated types, which it makes difficult to return a solid type like `String` or `Int` or `Bool`, because we have mixed type situation, then I am returning `Any` type, but I have to cast the return value later to String or Int or Bool, which I am not big fan of it, I was thinking maybe there is better way of using `Any` and thinking about generic, which generic could possibly infer the case type and returns the inferred type without having to deal with `Any` type anymore. Is it a way?

Comment: You can make an enum generic but you would loose the type constraints on the specific cases.

Comment: Get rid of `value` entirely. You use a `switch` statement in the caller to select the right case and get the right type. You'll need that anyway, since you need to know the type in order to use it. (If this is unclear, show some examples of how you think you would call use this type, and that should either make it clear or let us show you what needs to change.)

Comment: This looks like you might be better served by a struct

Comment: @RobNapier: The question goal and code example is in question, accessing the value of associated type when we are working with deferent value types.

Comment: @Jake: Yes, that is right but the question is about find a way for accessing the value of associated type when we are working with deferent value types.

Comment: What would it look like to "work with different value types?" What line of code would you write that would consume this value? What do you expect `testEnum.value + 1` to do if the value is a `.name`? You can definitely write a generic `value()` that returns different types through type inference, but would would you expect to happen if the value is wrong? Crash? Is there a default you'd use? Would it always be optional? Write the calling code first, and the data type will generally become clear.